# How to control image resolution (size) when using TakePhotoFromCameraAction (FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions) in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, android-camera, firemonkey, ios-camera, delphi-10.4-sydney

On both Android & iOS, I am successfully using `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction` in FMX to save photos taken by the user into a `TImage`.

When using `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction`, can I control the resolution (ultimately the size in bytes) of the photo that's taken? If so, how?

What is the best way to "post process" the resultant `TImage` to achieve a reduction in size? I ask this because I may need this functionality anyway if I am to begin using `TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction` to allow a user to choose an existing photo from their gallery.

I do need a solution that will work with both Android & iOS, please.

I am currently using Delphi 10.4.2 Sydney

Comment: I've removed your paragraph about purchasing a library, because its inclusion makes your post off-topic here. Questions asking (or implying that they'd like) a tool, software library or other off-site resources are not accepted here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: Not to you Ken but to the ridiculous guidelines... Isn't Delphi & FMX technically an off-site resource?

Comment: Delphi is an IDE and programming language, and questions related to using that IDE or code are entirely appropriate here. It would be an off-site resource if you were asking which programming language to use, which is entirely different. Read the guidelines that I linked, rather than making snarky remarks when people try to help you learn the guidelines to keep yourself out of trouble here. There's a difference between asking questions about use of a programming tool or library and asking about a recommendation for one. The guidelines make that distinction quite clear.

Comment: As far as your remark about the *ridiculous guidelines*, they exist to keep the garbage and noise away, to keep this a useful resource for programmers. If they're not to your liking, you're free to use one of the garbage collection sites like Reddit to ask your questions, but good luck finding anything with nearly as good quality there.

Answer (score 2):

> When using `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction`, can I control the resolution (ultimately the size in bytes) of the photo that's taken? If so, how?

[`TTakePhotoFromCameraAction`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions.TTakePhotoFromCameraAction) has [`MaxWidth`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions.TCustomTakePhotoAction.MaxWidth) and [`MaxHeight`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions.TCustomTakePhotoAction.MaxHeight) properties.

If you use [`IFMXCameraService.TakePhoto()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.IFMXCameraService.TakePhoto) instead, it has an overload that takes a [`TParamsPhotoQuery`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.TParamsPhotoQuery) parameter, which has a [`RequiredResolution`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.TParamsPhotoQuery.RequiredResolution) field.

> What is the best way to "post process" the resultant `TImage` to achieve a reduction in size? I ask this because I may need this functionality anyway if I am to begin using `TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction` to allow a user to choose an existing photo from their gallery.

[`TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions.TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction) also has [`MaxWidth`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions.TCustomTakePhotoAction.MaxWidth) and [`MaxHeight`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions.TCustomTakePhotoAction.MaxHeight)  properties.

And [`IFMXTakenImageService.TakeImageFromLibrary()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.IFMXTakenImageService.TakeImageFromLibrary) has an overload that has an `ARequiredResolution` parameter, and an overload that takes a [`TParamsPhotoQuery`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.MediaLibrary.TParamsPhotoQuery) parameter.

Comment: Thank you got your response. Sadly Embarcadero documentation gives zero explanation of those two very important properties.

Comment: Besides, then don't (always) work. On my Samsung S20+ the values are ignored and I always get a size of 960x720 pixels, no matter what I set these values to. I have tried setting it to 480x480 and 1024x1024 and in both cases, I get 960x720 (but the MaxWidth and MaxHeight of the TTakePhotoFromCameraAction instance still has the values I set).

Comment: @HeartWare  Were you able to solve the problem of photo quality ? 
I see that the problem is at the moment of Creating the photo. It has a low resolution.